Date of Exit is updated as Sunday in my experience letter
I was worked in a MNC as a contractor through a Consultancy through Consultancy pay roll which means I worked as Employee under the consultancy. I had PF from them.
In 2023, I'm moved as Full time employee, so From Monday they have appointment as full time employee under MNC company payroll.
So, in Consultancy pay roll they updated my Date of Exit in SUNDAY. I don't know which manner the Consultancy update my LWD /Date of Exit in SUNDAY, On that time, I didn't take this seriously.
But currently, I am worrying about that my Date of Exit is in SUNDAY. Is it cause any problems in future? Regarding BGV and PF related issues.
Please provide your suggestions ?

Welcome to the site, your question is full of acronyms which you no doubt understand but we don't - please spell them out in full the first time you use them (MNC/LWD/BGC/PF), some we can probably guess but might guess wrong.  Please also add the country you are in as that may influence answers.
Having said all that it sounds like you are finishing one contract on Sunday and starting a new one on the Monday - why do you think that is an issue?

You are starting as Full time for MNC, that means you're no longer a part of the consultancy company, if I am not missing something. If you're an MNC employee on Monday, you were a contractor on previous Sunday, why would this cause a problem?

If you were appointed to your current position on Monday and exited your previous position on Sunday.  What exactly are you worried about?

Please tag your question with the country you're from. I don't know any of the acronyms you're using, so I'm assuming you're not in the US.

to echo Sherry's sentiment - unless there is some additional detail I am missing - you worked as a contractor, and then moved full-time. You started full-time on the Monday and so your last day as a contractor was the day before - I am failing to see any issue.

@StephanBranczyk, I am not from India. But, all those acronyms seem to indicate that the OP is in India. MNC = Multi-National Company. BGV = Background Verification. Exit letter = from India.

Many systems allow Sunday or Monday to be set as the first day of the week. If their system is set as Sunday or Monday fine...

If you transfer straight from one company to another company, without being jobless/unemployed in-between, then it is entirely normal that the old company has the last calendar day before you started at the new company as your last day of employment (or last working day if that is the terminology they use).
It is not relevant if you performed actual work on that day or not. What is relevant is that the old company was paying your salary up till that day, for the rest it doesn't matter if it happens to be a non-working day (weekend, public holiday, etc.), a day you worked or if you were enjoying some left-over paid-time-off.
